Empty space between text and page number
I'm working on a LaTeX document, and instead of adding one more line at the bottom of the page (in the left column), it leaves a space and continues the text in the next column. I understand that LaTeX sometimes makes adjustments to optimize text layout, but in this case, I've tried reducing the text before and after, and nothing has changed. This issue only occurs on this specific page. Do you have any insights into why this might be happening?


Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is, please, your MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimal-working-example-mwe?

First, use  showframe (geometry package) to show the bottom of the text area.  This will show which line (or both) is out of position.

@JohnKormylo It seems like there is an extra line in the right. It only happens in this specific page. What can I do to fix it?

It could be any number of things.  Witout more information there is nothing we can do.
